# Retrieve the data from Text File

Tags: c#

I have a little project. What I am doing is, taking inputs from users and saving it in a text file. Its working good.

```
private void btbsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create Directory
    DirectoryInfo dd = new DirectoryInfo("C://Program Files/UserInfo");
    dd.Create();
    //To save the inputs
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C://Program Files/UserInfo/UserInfo.txt", true);
    sw.WriteLine(txtname.Text);
    sw.WriteLine(txtage.Text);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
    //Conformation
    MessageBox.Show("Credentials Saved");
    //To Clear the text box after data saved
    txtname.Text = string.Empty;
    txtage.Text = string.Empty;
    //Focus
    txturl.Focus();
}
```

And now, I want to retrieve the data depending on the inputs. This part is difficult for me, can you guys help me out?

```
private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C://Program Files/UserInfo/UserInfo.txt");
     String mystring = sr.ReadToEnd();
     //No idea how to retrive now plz help!
}
```

Brief description of my project:
Take some values from users like *UserName* and *Age*. Save them in a text file.

I need to retrieve values based on user *UserName*. I should then get *UserName* along with his *Age* and insert these values into 2 different readonly text boxes.

Comment: What path syntax is this `"C://Program Files/UserInfo"` based on? Never saw something like this before.

Comment: What do you mean "No idea how to retrive now"? The content of the file is in `mystring`, do you need anything else?

Comment: hello, why don't use xml file to store user information, text file are not usefull to do this

Answer (score 4):

Personally I'd advise you to rethink your approach, but here's what you're looking for:

```
    string sUserToSearch = "username";
    string sAgeToSearch = "22";

    string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines("UserInfo.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < readText.count-2; i++) {
         if(readText[i] == sUserToSearch && readText[i+1] == sAgeToSearch);
             // Found it!
    }
```

I don't know what you're trying to do, but if I got you correct, you should read more on [Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/index)

Comment: hello, you have right but it is a bad practice so is it good to make an  answer on a bad practice?

Comment: @HassanBoutougha Even though it _is_ a bad practice, Shai sent the OP to a guide on a better practice, and even says "Personally I'd advise you to rethink your approach, but here's what you're looking for"

Answer (score 1):

First you have to seperate your data at the time, you insert them to your textfile

```
private void WriteUserToFile(User user, string path)
{
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(user.Name + ";" + user.Age);
    }
}
```

Now you have a file like this:

```
User1;10
User2;20
User3;45
```

Now you have the possibility to split your data:

```
private IEnumerable<User> ReadUsersFromTextFile(string path)
{
    var users = new List<User>();

    using(var sr = new StringReader(path)
    {
        do
        {
            var strings = sr.ReadLine().split(';');                 
            var user = new User();
            user.Name = strings[0];
            user.Age = strings[1];
            users.Add(user);
        }while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    }

    return users;
}
```